# Is it possible to get Lat and Lon from GeoPoint from parseplaform using php

Tags: php, parse-platform

I wanna get lat and lon from GeoPoint, i've been trying many ways like this

```
$cordquery = new ParseQuery("Object");
    $cordquery->equalTo("cityCode", 1);
    $xd = $cordquery->find();
    
    foreach($xd as $g){
    $geopoint = $g->get('location');
    //$lat=$geopoint->get('latitude');
    echo $geopoint['Object']['latitude'];
}
```

But i cannot use object of type Parse\ParseGeoPoint as array. In docs i hadnt found any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i resolved this problem by geting location first, then i used function getLatitude.

```
    $cordquery = new ParseQuery("Object");
    $cordquery->equalTo("cityCode", 1);
    $xd = $cordquery->find();
    
    foreach($xd as $g){
    $geopoint = $g->get('location');
    $lat=$geopoint->getLatitude();
    echo $lat;
}
```